# Visual Studio 2015 Community: Commit to github via command line produces inaccessible file...?

Tags: github, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

[image]

I create a new repo on Github and follow the instructions.

Then I open Command Prompt and follow Github's instructions.

The picture is what I get...what appears to be file containing my project that is inaccessible.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an "inaccessible file", but a nested git repo.

It is recorded in the main git repo (published on GitHub) as a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309), and is displayed as a gray icon.

If you really want its content, you [should transform it as a submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28306781/6309).
As such, that gitlink points to nothing, as there is no way to know the remote url of that repo (only its SHA1 which is what the gitlink records)