# How do I get git submodule changes from parent to child repository?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a project repo (the parent) that contains a submodule (the child).

While working in the parent, I have made changes to the files of the child. I've committed those changes in the parent.

How do I get those changes back over to the child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a commit your changes in the child submodule folder, where you can also git push back to its own upstream repo.

*Then* you go back to the parent, add and commit the new [gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309) (**[special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)**, referencing the new SHA1 of the submodule), and push.

After [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163186/discussion-between-bob-rockefeller-and-vonc), the OP mentions:

> `/Users/bob/Documents/Web Development/Projects/materialize` is a public available theme for the Grav open source CMS.
>   `/Users/bob/Sites/www.materialize.dev` is the development version of a private website that uses the theme.
>
> I can't add, commit, and push from the child because edits made in the parent's folder structure do not show as changes in the child, and so there's nothing to commit.
>   My objective is to develop the website (parent) as a way to develop the theme (child). So I edit in the parent. The theme is published as a complete package on GitHub, the website is not. Am I going about this all in the wrong way from the start?

I do mention that a submodule should be able to ignore what the parent repo is doing (it is simply referenced by said parent repo at a fixed commit).
So the current structure might not be a good fit for the type of development the OP is after.

Comment: When I edit a file belonging to the child from within a folder in the parent, the parent recognizes the change and I can make a commit to the parent. But the child doesn't show any changes in its working directory, so I don't have the opportunity to make a commit there.

Comment: @BobRockefeller Then it is not a submodule: does the parent repo have a .gitmodules?

Comment: I'm convinced that it is a submodule. I created it with the Mac git client Tower and it shows as a submodule in the .gitmodules file.

Comment: So how about doing a commit from within the submodule itself, and pushing from there, before doing the same commit in the parent and pushing? (that is what I am describing in my answer)

Comment: The submodule's working directory is clean. It sees no changes to commit. :(

Comment: @BobRockefeller When you are pushing your main repo to a remote Git hosting service (for instance GitHub), do you see a gray folder as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/36684556/6309?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163186/discussion-between-bob-rockefeller-and-vonc).