# Git repo not updating github.io content

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

Git newbie here. Have searched Stackoverflow for this but nothing matches.

I have been committing/pushing my files for the last 8 weeks. However this week it seems to have gone wrong.

- My git repo (https://github.com/alice-tlr/alice-tlr.github.io) is showing the updated files, that match my local dev files
- However they are not reflected in the live https://alice-tlr.github.io site
- Git reports everything is up to date when i try push

Have also tried backing up & the deleting various folders and re-cloning. The push is successful but still the github.io site doesn't update.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folders you are trying to update in [`github.com/alice-tlr/alice-tlr.github.io`](https://github.com/alice-tlr/alice-tlr.github.io) are **nested git repo** recorded as **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, a [special entry in the index of the repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309).

A gitlink is just a SHA1 of another repo, as your [commit bcc3d31](https://github.com/alice-tlr/alice-tlr.github.io/commit/bcc3d31e1110d52cf23ead5a930cbfb594524a41) illustrate:

[image: gitlink update]

Those are the gray folder you see in your GitHub repo.

[image: github with nested repos]

They won't ever include files directly.

You can **[transform them as full-fledged submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28306781/6309)**.
They will still be gitlinks, meaning still a gray folder, but this time, [GitHub page can fetch their content and display it](https://help.github.com/articles/using-submodules-with-pages/)  (provided those submodules reference *public* repositories)

An actual submodule is:

- a gitlink (a SHA1)
- an url (that is the part which is missing currently)

Note that you can also [remove the nested git repo and add directly its content if you want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25093098/6309).

Comment: Thank you for your response, since posting i established this to be the issue and have resolved it - but thanks for taking the time to help.