# github moved repo showing as submodules and can't be opened

Tags: github

Repo A has several branches on it which were un merged. 
Repo B has several folders within it. Moved repo A into the folders inside the Repo B and now it shows as submodule and can't be opened on github. However, the original Repo A still exists outside the repo B. 
currently it's like this:

```
 Repo A ---- has many branches un merged.

 Repo B/ folder xyz/ Repo A(it looks grey like submodules and can't be opened)
```

an image of how it looks and can't be opened:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it cannot be opened, the react folder is likely to be a [gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) ([special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309) of the main repo)

If you don't have a `.gitmodules` file in your main repo, then this gray folder is not actually a submodule, but a [nested git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40818828/6309) (meaning just a SHA1, without any idea of the repo actual remote url).

You could convert it [into an actual submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28306781/6309): in that case, it would still be a gray folder, but this time with a link associated to it: see "[Working with submodules](https://github.com/blog/2104-working-with-submodules)":

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/2077/12631413/ce5590e2-c516-11e5-803b-116c5ac2d2b5.png]