# Django project folder doesn’t push to gitlab

Tags: django, gitlab

When I try to push my Django project into my gitlab repository it, all the files gets pushed properly except for the project folder it gets uploaded with a remove icon and text next to it that looks like that: @ it 1080bae7

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a submodule, or at least a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309)** (just a SHA1 entry)

Check if you see a `.gitmodules` in your repo.
If you don't see one, that means you have a nested git repo.

You can

- convert that folder (nested repo) [into an actual submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28306781/6309), or
- [merge the nested repo into your main repo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/277029/6309).

Comment: I have tried that and didn't work. i then tried to remove and create new repo multiple time didn't work so i create a new gitlab account and again didn't work. do you have django experience?

Answer (score 0):

I renamed the folder, pushed it and renamed it again.